# Why is action icon not showing on actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, overflow, action

I develop android application and I want to create action placed on action bar that is visible as icon. I added a drawable with resolution of 18x18px and created menu with one item, which is my action, as shown below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".RelationsActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_show_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon_16"
    android:title="@string/action_show_profile"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

As you can see the showAsAction attribute is set to "always" and it is still not working. I tried with different AppThemes and nothing helped. There surely is enough space for the icon cuz action bar title is disabled:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The action is present in the overflow dropdown as if there is no space for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And this method too

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU_FILE, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My activity extends Activity class not AppCompatActivity so I cannot use getSupportActtionBar() function but I tried with getActionBar() and it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
implements AppCompatCallback

and use this code inside oncreate method

  //let's create the delegate, passing the activity at both arguments (Activity, AppCompatCallback)
        AppCompatDelegate  delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);

        //we need to call the onCreate() of the AppCompatDelegate
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //we use the delegate to inflate the layout
        //delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync_contact);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);// icon of navigation 
        toolbar.setTitle("Inbox");
        delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: if any problem to use this code so please let me know. Thank you